# cannot convert from 'System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase' to 'string'

Tags: asp.net, drawing

```
var file = Request.Files[0];
                    //HttpPostedFileBase hpf = Request.Files[0];

                    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                    {
                        //var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);                        
                        var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
                        var allowedExtensions = new[] { ".bmp", ".png", ".jpg", "jpeg", ".gif" };
                        if (allowedExtensions.Contains(fileExtension))
                        {
                            //Delete files
                            var pathD = Server.MapPath("~/Avatar/1");
                            var images = Directory.GetFiles(pathD, CustomerID + ".*");
                            for (int i = 0; i < images.Length; i++)
                                System.IO.File.Delete(Server.MapPath(("~/Avatar/1/") + Path.GetFileName(images[i])));

                            //Up files
                            var fileName = CustomerID + fileExtension;
                            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Avatar/1/"), fileName);
```

everything works fine but getting a problem with one line

```
                            System.Drawing.Image imageToBeResized = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(file);
                            int imageHeight = imageToBeResized.Height;
                            int imageWidth = imageToBeResized.Width;
                            int maxHeight = 400;
                            int maxWidth = 400;
                            imageHeight = (imageHeight * maxWidth) / imageWidth;
                            imageWidth = maxWidth;

                            if (imageHeight > maxHeight)
                            {
                                imageWidth = (imageWidth * maxHeight) / imageHeight;
                                imageHeight = maxHeight;
                            }

                            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(imageToBeResized, imageWidth, imageHeight);
                            System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
                            bitmap.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                            stream.Position = 0;
                            byte[] imasave = new byte[stream.Length + 1];
                            stream.Read(imasave, 0, imasave.Length);

                            var newImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);
                            newImage.Save(path);
```

below line gaves me error when i pass file
               System.Drawing.Image imageToBeResized = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(file);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System.Drawing.Image.FromFile takes a string argument. instead of of giving it he file variable give the path you have obtained of the file and it will work.

```
 System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Path.GetFileName(file.Filename));
                                  or
   System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath(Path.GetFileName(file.Filename)));
```

Comment: System.Drawing.Image imageToBeResized = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile( Path.GetFullPath(file.FileName)); that gave me error i want to give path of any image which is loacted in my computer but i cant.any solution ??

Comment: System.Drawing.Image imageToBeResized = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile( Path.GetFullPath(file.FileName)); that gave me error i want to give path of any image which is loacted in my computer but i cant.any solution ??